# Hibernate not executing commands and freezes execution

Tags: java, hibernate

This seems like a dumb question, but I couldn't find a solution yet,
My program used to work fine, but now sometimes it stuck with hibernate commands, like:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(Nota nota) {
    System.out.println("This displays");
    session().saveOrUpdate(nota); 
    System.out.println("This don't");
}

public void deleteAll() {
    System.out.println("This delete displays");
    session().createQuery("delete from nota").executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("This don't");
}
```

I tried with both functions to test, and it shows the first display, then the program freezes in eclipse, with no error, no result, no database change and I have to stop manually the server.

I am getting the session from Spring

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: what does ´session()´do ?

Comment: It get's the current session from the sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Comment: base on your "answer" there is uncaught exceptions.  You should cover it in the question. -1 for poorly asked question with inadequate info.

Answer (score -1):

It might not be the solution, but if you surround the command with try catch you can see the real error, in my case:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value  violates unique constraint "pk"
```

and

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: pdfnota is not mapped [delete from pdfnota]
```